# Pencil Evolus How do I change the text color

Tags: evolus-pencil

I need to change the text color but I don't find how. I searched the wiki and help sections but found nothing.
Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Towards the right end of the toolbar there are three buttons for changing the text, fill and stroke colour of the selected item:

[image: Changing text colour from the toolbar]

You can also right-click on the element and choose *Properties* and from there change the text colour.